# Background image size inside flexbox not the same between Chrome and Firefox

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, flexbox, background-image

I have an interesting issue where the background image of an element is not showing up the same between the two browsers. Chrome 65, FF 59.

I'm using the technique to show a ratio of the background image using padding-top percentage, where height is zero.

A codepen is also included.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OvGeeJ

A quick thing to note. The content div was only for visually knowing when the flex container ended.

It seems like the way % is calculated is different.

```css
body{
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.flex{
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 300vh;
  background: black;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.stickybg{
  height:0;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/8bKkEfR.jpg);
  background-size: 100% auto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding-top: 19%;
}

.content{
  height: 100vh;
  background: #111;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="stickybg"></div>
</div>
<div class="content"></div>
```

Comment: Browser wars! Making web beautiful ;)

Comment: Could you test Firefox Beta 60 and see if that matches your expectations?  There was a recent flexbox specification change around handling of percent padding, which I addressed in Firefox 60 in https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=958714 (and which makes Firefox match Chrome)  Firefox Beta download link: https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/channel/desktop/

Comment: FF 60 works as expected! Thanks Dholbert keeping up with this 4 year old ticket.

Answer (score 0):

As dholbert said in a comment, it appears FF beta 60 has the issue fixed.

A workaround is to use VH or VW units which in my case would simulate the same thing.

Replacing

```
 padding-top: 19%;
```

for

```
 padding-top: 19vw;
```